# Relative positioned element shows over my fixed navbar

Tags: html, css

I made a fixed navbar and then a header that I used relative position to place it below the fixed navbar. But when I scroll up the header shows over the navbar.

```
<section class="nav-bar">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-left">LOGO</li>
    <li class="nav-right"><a href="">FACEBOOK</a></li>
    <li class="nav-right"><a href="">GITHUB</a></li>
    <li class="nav-right"><a href="">TREEHOUSE</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
<h1 class="head">THIS IS THE HEADER</h1>

h1 {
  position: relative;
  top:2em;
}
.nav-bar{
  background-color: blue;
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  margin-top:-1.25em;
  margin-left:-.55em;
  padding-bottom:1em;

}
```

Any advice on how to keep the header behind the navbar? I'm sure it has something to do with the fixed and relative positioning but haven't found anything on how to remedy this.

Comment: You must set z-index value in .nav-bar selector. If we do not set z-index for any dom element browsers by default set higher z-index in last dom in each siblings. So type something like that  .nav-bar {z-index:100}

Answer (score 1):

Hanif is right, adding `z-index` to `.nav-bar` achieves the effect you desire.

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  top:2em;
}
.nav-bar{
  background-color: blue;
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  margin-top:-1.25em;
  margin-left:-.55em;
  padding-bottom:1em;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<section class="nav-bar">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-left">LOGO</li>
    <li class="nav-right"><a href="">FACEBOOK</a></li>
    <li class="nav-right"><a href="">GITHUB</a></li>
    <li class="nav-right"><a href="">TREEHOUSE</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
<h1 class="head">THIS IS THE HEADER</h1>
```